# Run Pig embedded in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

When I try to to run the `pig` commands in grunt shell it is working. However, when I try to run it with `PigRunner` inside a Java program in local mode it is giving found interface but class expected error.

I am using `hadoop2.5.0cdh5.3.2` and `pig0.12.0`.

I have included the code for the `java` file

```
 public class local
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{

    try {test();}
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void test() throws IOException 
{
    File f1 = new File("myscript.pig");
    f1.deleteOnExit();

    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1);
    fw1.append("A = load '/home/ritika/NLP/Libraries/dict.txt' as words:chararray;");
    fw1.append("dump A;");
    fw1.close();

    String[] args = { "-x", "local", "myscript.pig" };
    PigStats stats = PigRunner.run(args, null);


}
}
```

**This is the error:**

> 2018-12-06 14:54:30,819 [JobControl] ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl - Error while
>   trying to run jobs. java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found
>   interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was
>   expected  at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:554)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:430)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)

Comment: have you try this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300612/error-in-pig-while-loading-data"

Comment: Yes i have. I mentioned the hadoop and pig version i am using already. It is running perfectly in batch mode and in grunt shell.